# Calendar Synchronization

Tags: iphone, mac, calendar

Why does my iPhone calendar not sync with my Mac computer calendar?  When I enter appointments in my Mac calendar they download automatically to my iPhone but when I enter an appointment in my iPhone it does not get synced or uploaded to my Mac.

Comment: Could you specify which method should use your synchronization (iCloud, USB cable, Wi-Fi) between your Mac & iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that both your Mac and iPhone have calendar in iCloud turned on. If they do, try logging out of iCloud and then logging back in. If not, try using another calendar account like Yahoo or Gmail.